# Sending images from android to remote MySQL database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, base64

Hi there im working on a piece of coursework where i am required to send data to a remote MySQL server with a PHP backend. Currently i'm having some issues with sending and receiving images.

What I am currently doing is encoding the image to base64 and sending it via http post to my server. I have checked the data being sent and its all fine. However it is not being processed by my PHP side of things correctly.

Here is what I am doing...

This is the method I use for the conversion of bitmap to string...

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String imageString=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I then send this imageString in a http post and it is received by the PHP script below

```
$uploadDIR = '../data/';
if ($_REQUEST['picture']!=null){

    $image = base64_decode($_REQUEST['picture']);
    $file = $uploadDIR . uniqid().'.jpeg';
file_put_contents($file, $image);
    $sql = "
                                            INSERT INTO comments
                                            (image)
                                            VALUES (
                                                    '".$file."'
                                                    )";


}
executeSQLQuery($sql);
```

After trying this a few times not even the file is being stored in that location.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: are you not able to recreate image from data you received ? or can you  more about the question.

Comment: No i guess i cant recreate an image from that data since its not creating an image file in the specified directory. Does my code seem ok?

Comment: Ok so i have created a log file PHP side of things and it seems like it isnt receiving the encoded image. it just gets NULL, however it is definately being sent as i checked on the java side of things...

Answer (score 0):

Code in java assuming that the image is already converted to bitmap:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmIcone.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
```

In server :

```
$base= $_REQUEST['image'];
$buffer = base64_decode($base);

$buffer = mysql_real_escape_string($buffer);
```